# Работа с Undo Framework в QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qtableview, undo-redo

Как реализовать операцию отмены и повтора в `QTableWidget` ?

Возьмём за пример простое окно с `QTableWidget` где будем отслеживать нажатие клавиш, при сочетании клавиш <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> действие отменяется, а при <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> повторяется.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(400, 400)

        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(10, 10)

        self.vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.tableWidget)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.text() == '<0x1a>':
            self.tableWidget.undo()
        elif event.text() == '<0x19>':
            self.tableWidget.redo()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Если вы знакомы с С++, то вот отличнейший пример: `https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tools-undoframework-example.html`

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Я про это и говорю то что я нашёл пример и документацию на C++ но не знаю как это сделать на python

Comment: Вот простенький пример https://programtalk.com/python-examples/PyQt5.Qt.QUndoCommand.__init__/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте проверить написанное ниже.
Если это то что вам надо, отслеживание нажатия сочетания клавиш
добавите самостоятельно.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class CommandTextEdit(QtWidgets.QUndoCommand):
    def __init__(self, window, index, oldText, newText): 
        super(CommandTextEdit,self).__init__()
        self.index = index
        self.window = window
        self.oldText = oldText
        self.newText = newText

    def redo(self):
        self.index.model().itemDataChanged.disconnect(self.window.itemDataChangedSlot)
        self.index.model().setData(self.index, self.newText, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
        self.index.model().itemDataChanged.connect(self.window.itemDataChangedSlot)

    def undo(self):
        self.index.model().itemDataChanged.disconnect(self.window.itemDataChangedSlot)
        self.index.model().setData(self.index, self.oldText, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
        self.index.model().itemDataChanged.connect(self.window.itemDataChangedSlot)


class Model(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    itemDataChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object, object, object, object)

    def __init__(self, data = [[]], parent = None):
        super(Model,self).__init__(parent)
        self._data = data

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self._data)
       
    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self._data[0])

    def data(self, index, role):
        row = index.row()
        column = index.column()
        if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            return self._data[row][column]

        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            value = self._data[row][column]
            return value      

    def model(self):
        return self

    def flags(self, index):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable | \
               QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled  | \
               QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable

    def setData(self, index, value, role = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1):
        if index.isValid():
           if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
                oldValue = self.data(index, role)
                self._data[index.row()][index.column()] = value
                self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
                if oldValue != value:
                    self.itemDataChanged.emit(index, oldValue, value, role)
                return True
        return False
        

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Window,self).__init__(parent)
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.setWindowTitle('Widget Mapping GUI')
        mainlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.mapper = None

        rowCount    = 5
        columnCount = 5
        data = [
            [f'{j}-{i}' for i in range(columnCount)]
             for j in range(rowCount)
        ]
        self.model = Model(data)
        
        #QUndoStack
        self.undoStack = QtWidgets.QUndoStack()
        self.stackView = QtWidgets.QUndoView(self.undoStack)

        self.createActions()
        self.makeConnections()
        self.tableViewMethod()
       
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        mainlayout.addLayout(layout)
        layout.addWidget(self.tableView)

    def createActions(self):
        self.undoAct = QtWidgets.QAction("Undo", self)
        self.undoAct.setShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence.Undo)
        self.undoAct.triggered.connect(self.undoStack.undo)
        self.redoAct = QtWidgets.QAction("Redo", self)
        self.redoAct.setShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence.Redo)
        self.redoAct.triggered.connect(self.undoStack.redo)
        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('')
        self.toolbar.addAction(self.undoAct)
        self.toolbar.addAction(self.redoAct)

    def tableViewMethod(self):
        self.tableView = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.tableView.setModel(self.model)
        self.tableView.setWindowTitle('tableView')

    def makeConnections(self):
        self.model.itemDataChanged.connect(self.itemDataChangedSlot)

    def setModel(self, model):
        self.mapper = QtWidgets.QDataWidgetMapper(self)
        self.mapper.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.mapper.setModel(model)
        
    def itemDataChangedSlot(self, index, oldValue, value, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            command = CommandTextEdit(
                self, 
                index, 
                oldValue, 
                value
            )
            self.undoStack.push(command)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.resize(600, 300)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно ли реализовать то же самое но с QtableWidget ?

Comment: @assert , QTableWidget имеет своя модель только для чтения, 
поэтому вы не можете заменить ее другой моделью.
Почитайте Model/View Tutorial https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/modelview.html
для общего представления.